# TLE in RECTNG1 spoj problem on finding the number of separate blocks formed by rectangles with integer coordinates

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to solve 
[the SPOJ problem on rectangles](http://www.spoj.com/problems/RECTNG1/).
Problem statement:

> There are n rectangles drawn on the plane. Each rectangle has sides parallel to the coordinate axes and integer coordinates of vertices.
>   We define a block as follows:
>
> - each rectangle is a block,
> - if two distinct blocks have a common segment then they form the new block otherwise we say that these blocks are separate.
>
> Write a program that for each test case:
>
> - reads the number of rectangles and coordinates of their vertices;
> - finds the number of separate blocks formed by the rectangles;
> - writes the result to the standard output.
>
> Input:
>
> The number of test cases t is in the first line of input, then t test cases follow separated by an empty line.
>
> In the first line of a test case there is an integer n, 1 <= n <= 7000, which is the number of rectangles. In the following n lines there are coordinates of rectangles. Each rectangle is described by four numbers: coordinates x, y of the bottom-left vertex and coordinates x, y of the top-right vertex. All these coordinates are non-negative integers not greater than 10000.
>
> Output:
>
> For each test case you should output one line with the number of separate blocks formed by the given rectangles.

My approach:

1. Check for every pair of rectangle `r_i` and `r_j` whether they are separate or not based on that set adjacency matrix `mat[i][j]` and `mat[j][i]` to true or false respectively
2. Then run DFS on the constructed graph to count number of connected paths. This count will represent number of separate block.

As number of rectangles is at most 7000, looking at every pair will not cross 10^7. Still I am getting TLE (time limit exceeded).

How can I solve this problem more efficiently?

```cpp
void comp() {
    list.clear();

    scanI(n);

    REP(i,1,n) {
         Rec rec;
        scanI(rec.p);
        scanI(rec.q);
        scanI(rec.r);
        scanI(rec.s);
        list.pb(rec);
    }
    REP(i,0,list.size()-2){
        Rec rec = list[i];
        p = rec.p;
        q = rec.q;
        r = rec.r;
        s = rec.s;

        REP(j,i+1,list.size()-1) {
            Rec m = list[j];
            a = m.p;
            b = m.q;
            c = m.r;
            d = m.s;
            if(!isSeparate()) {
                eList[i].pb(j); //adjacency list for rec_i
                eList[j].pb(i);//adjacency list for rec_j
            }
        }
    }

    int cnt=0;
    REP(i,0,n-1) {
        if(!vis[i]){
            cnt++;
            dfs(i);
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n",cnt);
}

bool isSeparate(){
    if(s<b || d<q || r<a || c<p) return true;
    if((r==a && q==d)||(c==p && b==s)||(a==r && b==s)||(p==c && q==d)) return true;
    else return false;
}

void dfs(int s) {
    cout<<"Visited : "<<s<<endl;
    if(vis[s]) return;
    vis[s] = true;
    REP(i,0,eList[s].size()-1){
        if(!vis[eList[s][i]]){
            dfs(eList[s][i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please put the problem statement in the question itself.

Comment: `As number of rectangles is at most 7000, looking at every pair will not cross 10^7` Actually the number of pairs is `2.45 * 10^7` still this is not too much. Maybe your algorithm is not optimized? Could you paste your code?

Comment: Could it be simply your `cout<<"Visited : "<<s<<endl;`?  I/O takes time (and of course causes a wrong answer).

Comment: BTW your DFS will count the number of connected *components*, which is much less than the number of connected *paths*.

Comment: Low-level ideas: In `if(s<b || d<q || r<a || c<p)` and the following `if`, you can get up to 8 mispredicted branches.  It *may* be a small constant factor faster to replace each `||` with `|` or `+` to avoid the short-circuiting, meaning you do more calculation on average but have at most 2 mispredicted branches.  Also is `list` a `std::vector`?  I was surprised to find that a standard `for` loop counting from 0 up to `v.size()` generates `IMUL` instructions in both MSVC++13 and g++!

Comment: `cout<<"visited : "<<s<<endl;`I used this for debugging, I commented it each time i submit the solutiong

Comment: I am not getting why DFS wont work here. Can you give me example. And thanks for the branching idea, it sounds good. And yes list is vector of Rectangles.

Comment: DFS works in the sense that it's *correct*; it's just that you will be doing a large number of operations in the worst case, and this particular problem is running on a very old computer (750MHz Pentium III!).  The SPOJ "About" page mentions that they are 30-50x slower than typical modern computers (e.g. what you're probably testing on at home).  P.S. Write "@j_random_hacker" in a comment, or I won't be notified.

Comment: @j_random_hacker ohhh thanks i dont know that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've thought of a couple of more algorithmic improvements.

Use a **fast union/find data structure** instead of building an adjacency-list representation of the graph.  Then if one rectangle intersects another rectangle you can stop right then -- there's no need to continue testing it against all other rectangles seen so far.  With this in place, problem instances in which most rectangles intersect most other rectangles will be solved very quickly.

There's still the need to efficiently handle problem instances in which most rectangles intersect few or no other rectangles.  A couple of observations:

- A rectangle can only overlap another rectangle if both their vertical and horizontal extents overlap.
- If we have n non-overlapping rectangles centered at the grid points of some h*w grid, it must be that min(h, w) <= sqrt(n).

Suppose the problem instance has the form of the second bullet point above -- an h*w grid of non-overlapping rectangles, with h*w = n but h and w otherwise unknown.  As you process each rectangle, insert its vertical extent into a data structure that enables fast point-in-interval queries, such as an interval tree or segment tree, and insert its horizontal extent into another such data structure.  The obvious way of using this information -- by looking up all rectangles that overlap the current rectangle vertically, and looking up all rectangles that overlap it horizontally, and then intersecting these 2 lists -- doesn't give much speed advantage, because one of these lists could be very long.  What you can do instead is to simply **pick the shorter of these 2 lists** and test every rectangle in it (as before, stopping as soon as an overlap is detected).  This is fast, because we know that the shorter list can have at most sqrt(7000) rectangles in it.

I haven't proven that a grid of non-overlapping rectangles is a true worst case for this algorithm, but I'm confident the above approach will work quickly in any case.